# Where is contact tag data saved in Google Drive/photo?

Tags: google-drive-api, drive, google-photos

I'd like to make an app that allows my organization to add custom tags on top of what's provided in Google Drive/Google Photos. Google photos creates custom albums for each of your contacts, and when you take a new picture, it automatically tags contacts in photos. Where is that data stored? Looking at the Google Drive Rest API for Files (https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files?hl=en), it doesn't appear to be anywhere. What I'd ultimately like to do is filter the photos in my Google Drive account by contact. Is that possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google photos are stored in the drive containers but the photos data is still stored in the old Picasa infrastructure.  you can try with the [Picasa api](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/faq)